# Mask tensor with indices

Tags: python, tensorflow, mask

Given a 2D tensor `x` of size `(batch_size, D)` and vectors `m1` and `m2` of masking indices each of size `(batch_size, )`, how can I mask the tensor such that values at indices in row `i` of `x` that are less than `m1[i]` or greater than `m2[i]` are set to 0? Note that `m1` and `m2` refer to indices (not values), `m1[i]` is guaranteed to be less than or equal to `m2[i]`, and different rows may have different numbers of values that are not masked.

For example, with `x` of size `(2, 4)` and `m1` and `m2` of size `(2, )`:

```
# input
x = tf.Variable([[1., 2., -1., 5.], [4., -3., 3., -2]])
m1 = tf.Variable([1, 2])
m2 = tf.Variable([2, 2])

# desired masked result
y = tf.Variable([[0., 2., -1., 0.], [0., 0., 3., 0.]])
```

Here, the first row has two non-masked values, while the second row only has one. I am using TensorFlow 2.

Comment: I guess you mean `row i of x which is less than m1[i] OR greater than m2[i]`, not AND.

Comment: That's right, sorry for the confusion. Values in indices between m1[i] and m2[i] should remain the same while values outside this window should be set to zero.

Comment: In the example, with m1[0] = 1 and m2[0] = 2, x[0][0] will be set to zero, x[0][1;2] remain the same, and x[0][3] will be set to zero.

Comment: Following this: `row i of x which is less than m1[i]==1 OR greater than m2[i]==2`, the result for the first row must be `[ 0.  0. -1.  5.]`. You need to clarify what do you want

Comment: Sorry, but how did you get [0,. 0., -1., 5.]? x[0] = [1., 2., -1., 5.], so x[0][0] = 1. x[0][1] = 2. x[0][2] = -1., and x[0][3] = 5. Since m1[0] = 1 and m2[0] = 2, x[0][1] and x[0][2] should remain the same while x[0][0] and x[0][3] are set to zero. Does this make sense?

Comment: `m1` and `m2` refer to indices, not values.